# Vertical line vs perpendicular line

Tags: geometry, 3d

Suppose I have a 2D plane.

In a nutshell, my question is that suppose there is a straight line AB perpendicular to that plane. Can I say that AB is a vertical line too?

I actually don't have much intuition about lines positioned vertically with respect to a plane.

If there's any problem in my question please inform me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please choose your tags with care. Your question is not about `plane-geometry`.

Comment: See [Horizontal_and_vertical in_three_dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_and_vertical#In_three_dimensions).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you please suggest one? Thanks

Comment: @G.Sassatelli The straight line is positioned vertically with respect to the plane

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan you just repeated the same wording as was given in the question^. What does that actually mean? Perpendicular? I think the confusion is about which direction is vertical or horizontal. Perhaps if this is not what you mean, you could provide a picture or diagram to explain?

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan `3d` seems to be a better choice. Or simply `geometry`.

Comment: @JohnDoe , yeah, sorry for that. My question is that suppose there is a straight line AB perpendicular to a plane. Can I say that AB is a vertical line too?

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan Sure - you could define "vertical" to mean that. The phrase "vertically with respect to a plane" is not actually commonly used, so could cause confusion. Having said that, I can't imagine it to mean anything other than that it is perpendicular to the plane. I'd just stick to saying it is perpendicular though, so there is no possibility of confusion.

Comment: I think "vertical" implies an up/down situation, i.e. gravity.  Since geometry abstracts from the physical, "perpendicular" is better than "vertical".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you designate a certain plane as "the horizontal plane," then any lines perpendicular to that plane are vertical. People do this sometimes, for example when speaking of the "vertical line test."

Once you have chosen a horizontal plane, however, I do not recall any precedent for saying that other lines are vertical "with respect to" some other plane. It defeats the purpose of naming one direction as "vertical," because you would always have to ask, "Vertical with respect to what?"

Since "perpendicular to" is less effort to write than "vertical with respect to," (fewer words *and* fewer letters), why not just write "perpendicular to" when you mean "perpendicular to"?

Comment: thanks, for the answer

Comment: Also, another advantage of "perpendicular to" is that it can be shortened further with the symbol: $\perp$.